# How two interact from two sources (view) and other Module in parallel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I have a Module for a hardware, which shall be possible to interact from View by the User and from another Module.

**Question:**

Shall I create a singleton instance in the MyModule_A, register this instance two my container and use this container to resolve the instance in MyModule_B?

**Or**

Shall I have to use a Eventaggregator two communicate between the two Modules?

The prism documentation is for me not clear in that case.

- Solution commanding. Use when there is an expectation of immediate
  action from the user interaction.
- Region context. Use this to provide contextual information between
  the host and views in the host's region. This approach is somewhat
  similar to the DataContext, but it does not rely on it.
- Shared services. Callers can call a method on the service which
  raises an event to the receiver of the message. Use this if none of
  the preceding is applicable.
- Event aggregation. For communication across view models, presenters,
  or controllers when there is not a direct action-reaction
  expectation.

  ```
  public class MyModule_A : IModule
  ```

  {
      IRegionManager _regionManager;
      private IUnityContainer _container;
      private ILoggerFacade _logger;

  ```
  public MyModule(IRegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer container)
  {
      regionManager = regionManager;
      _container = container;
  }

  public void Initialize()
  {
      _unityContainer.RegisterType<IMyHardware, MyHardware>(new Containercontrolledlifetime);
  }
  ```

  }

  public class MyModule_AViewModel : BindableBase
  {
      private string _title = "MyModule_A";
      private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
      private readonly IUnityContainer _unityContainer;
      private readonly IUnityContainer _unityContainer;
      private readonly ILoggerFacade _logger;
      private IMyHardware _myhardware;

  ```
  public string Title
  {
      get { return _title; }
      set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
  }

  public MyModuleViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer unityContainer)
  {
      _unityContainer = unityContainer;
      _logger = unityContainer.Resolve<ILoggerFacade>();
      _myhardware = unityContainer.Resolve<IMyHardware>();
      _logger.Log("ViewModel created", Category.Debug, Priority.Medium);
  }


  public class MyModule_B : IModule
  {
      IRegionManager _regionManager;
      private IUnityContainer _container;
      private ILoggerFacade _logger;
      private IHardware _myhardware;

      public MyModule(IRegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer container)
      {
          regionManager = regionManager;
          _container = container;
      }

      public void Initialize()
      {
      }
  }

  public class MyModule_BViewModel : BindableBase
  {
      private string _title = "MyModule_B";
      private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
      private readonly IUnityContainer _unityContainer;
      private readonly ILoggerFacade _logger;
      private IMyHardware _myhardware;
      public string Title
      {
          get { return _title; }
          set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
      }

      public MyModule_BViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, unityContainer unityContainer)
      {
          _unityContainer = unityContainer;
          _logger = unityContainer.Resolve<ILoggerFacade>();
          _myhardware = unityContainer.Resolve<IMyHardware>();
          _logger.Log("ViewModel created", Category.Debug,Priority.Medium);
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: Looks like you could just inject the MyModule into the MyModuleViewModel, wouldn't that be what you need?

Comment: In case, if then I have all properties, commands and instances which are in my MyViewModel, but so fare I understood, if I inject the MyModule, then I dont have the properties,commands etc. which are created inside of the ViewModel. Please adivice me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: Still not very clear, not even what you mean by 'remote'.

Comment: Remote means remoting by other Module

Comment: Still not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a shared service, i.e. this:

> Shall I create a singleton instance in the MyModule_A, register this instance two my container and use this container to resolve the instance in MyModule_B?

Create an interface for your driver in a third assembly (not a module) referenced by module a and module b. Then register the driver in module a, and have it injected in the view model or whatever in module b or c or even a.

Sketch:

```
// in the interface-assembly:

public interface IDriver
{
    bool ReadSensor();
}

// in module a:

internal class MyDriver : IDriver ...

public class MyModuleA : IModule
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _container.RegisterType<IDriver, MyDriver>( new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() );
    }
}

// in module b:

internal class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel( IDriver theHardware ) ...
}
```

Comment: I read yesterday several times the prism docu,about the shared services, global command and EventAggregator. I understood your example and it helps alot, but one point is still unclear. How I handle the problem, that one module was not loaded and the implementation of the interface assembly is missing? Shall I create in the Interface Assembly a implemenation with virtual methods and send a error message? If the Module A was not loaded and Module B tries to execute the method, then my program doesnt run into a exception. The Module overrides the virtual methods of the infracture implemenation.

Comment: If the module is not loaded at all, something went wrong. If the module is loaded too late, make the "using" module dependent on the "providing" module so that the module containing the driver is loaded first. If you don't want to load all modules before actually starting the app, that is.